# Special case of Faulhaber's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

Consider the following sum $$S_p(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^p$$ for the special case $p = n$. Is there any known closed form formula/bound(s) for this case?

Comment: Why not still use Faulhaber's formula, but with $p=n$?

Answer (score 0):

By Riemann sums:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^n = n^{n+1}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\right)\approx n^{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}x^n\,dx = \frac{n^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

Comment: The result can be further simplified to just $n^n$.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how you really show that!

Comment: @PTDS: it is quite trivial that the dominant contribute to the sum is given by the last term only. So you may divide your sum by $n^n$, then estimate $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n $$ in your favourite way.